# Right place to ask? Whatsapp using Android default emoji rather than Whatsapp's own

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, emoticons

I use SwiftKey, and have never run into this before. After googling it, Swiftkey's official site says it should use WhatsApp's emojis over Androids, is there a way for me to see what caused the switch and swap it back?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? I mean how did you get Android emoji in WhatsApp? Are you sure you're pressing on the right thing?